# Drawing complex polygons with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, polygon-creation

In PyQGIS, I kwnow how to draw polygons starting from a list of points which represent the nodes of the shape. An example of list could be this:

```
# First polygon
list_1 = [QgsPoint(0,0),QgsPoint(0,50),QgsPoint(50,50),QgsPoint(50,0)]

# Second polygon
list_2 = [QgsPoint(10,10),QgsPoint(10,30),QgsPoint(30,30),QgsPoint(30,20)]
```

which lead to the representation of these polygons:

[image]

If I manually do some operations, I can create a unique polygon like this one:

[image]

My question is: Is there a specific rule or a particular way to handle points (in or outside a list) for obtaining the result above? I only know that, for simple polygons, the points must to be ordered clockwise.

My goal is similar to that one in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97623/howto-create-complex-polygon-with-pyshp) question, but I think that the context is different here.

Comment: You need a list of lists where the first and last point match on each sub-list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this kind of list (where the first and last point match on each sub-list):

```
pol = [[QgsPoint(0,0),QgsPoint(0,50),QgsPoint(50,50),QgsPoint(50,0),QgsPoint(0,0)],
       [QgsPoint(10,10),QgsPoint(10,30),QgsPoint(30,30),QgsPoint(30,20),QgsPoint(10,10)]]

pol_wkt = QgsGeometry.fromPolygon(pol).exportToWkt()

print pol_wkt
```

I created an objet of **QgsGeometry** (Python Console of QGIS) to get its expression in WKT format. By using QuickWKT plugin, it can be observed that the result is identical to yours.

[image]

**Editing Note:**

As order (outer ring must include inner rings) and intersection of inner polygons is very important, it could be necessary to validate the geometry before printing it. In next case, where the original order of sub-lists was interchanged, the geometry is not valid:

```
pol = [[QgsPoint(10,10),QgsPoint(10,30),QgsPoint(30,30),QgsPoint(30,20),QgsPoint(10,10)],
       [QgsPoint(0,0),QgsPoint(0,50),QgsPoint(50,50),QgsPoint(50,0),QgsPoint(0,0)]]

if QgsGeometry.fromPolygon(pol).isGeosValid():
    pol_wkt = QgsGeometry.fromPolygon(pol).exportToWkt()

    print pol_wkt

else:
    print "geometry is not valid"
```

Comment: + 1 That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! =)

Comment: Please, see my 'Editing Note'.